# A typical Bar graph Using D3JS or any other library with interactions. Can someone help on this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

Can we draw the below bar chart using d3js? In My view it looks very complex, Can someone help me to draw this?[image]

Interactions:

On launch first, the Yellow bar lines should animate and after a couple of seconds, below(Blue) bars with different input values should animate.

The bone lines should be shown when I select any of the years on X-axis. Kindly help with this challenging task. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are few questions in one post. Where is exactly a difficult part: to draw animated bars (first yellow then blue), or the "bone lines" ?

Comment: I am able to plot the Yellow bars, but how do I form blue bars and bone lines?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?